# Running multiple CMD commands on one line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying the following script in one line by adding the & does not work:

```
set flag=0

if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe" (set flag=1)

if exist "%public%\Desktop\TeamViewer.lnk" (set /a flag +=1)

if %flag% equ 0 (echo "1" > "%programdata%\Heimdal Security\Patching\teamviewer-first-install.txt")

if %flag% equ 2 (echo "1" > "%programdata%\Heimdal Security\Patching\teamviewer.txt")
```

The script runs fine if I run each command on its line.

The code that I want to run as a single line is:

```
set flag=0 & if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe" (set flag=1) & if exist "%public%\Desktop\TeamViewer.lnk" (set /a flag +=1) & if %flag% equ 0 (echo "1" > "%programdata%\Heimdal Security\Patching\teamviewer-first-install.txt") & if %flag% equ 2 (echo "1" > "%programdata%\Heimdal Security\Patching\teamviewer.txt")
```

Could you give me a hint if this is possible or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see any `&`s in your example code. What does your code look like when you try to combine lines? You're probably close (although I see _way_ too many parentheses in your code).

Comment: When the first `if` isn't true, the second one is not even evaluated - and none of the commands afterward. You need another logic.